# data gets deleted without any cascade delete options added to sql alchemy

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have three tables in a PostgreSQL database. They have foreign key constraints as follows:

```
one(id, name)
two(id, name, foreignkey(one(id))
three(id, name, foreignkey(two(id))
```

The behavior I want is that if I delete a row from table "one", the corresponding rows should get deleted from table "two" and "three". I have added the "on delete cascade" constraint in my database.

It works fine when I try to delete an entry in the database through its cli.

I checked on sqlalchemy docs for code changes to add this behavior through sqlalchemy, and they suggest adding relationship and cascade delete parameters, like this

```
class User(Base):
    # ...

    addresses = relationship("Address", cascade="all, delete")
```

but it works without adding these.

My question is what is "relationship" in sqlalchemy and why does it work without adding those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone wondering about this question. I got the answer.
Sql alchemy is a wrapper over the database, it does not control the database, it will convert the written queries into a query which your database can understand. If your database has some constraints, then it will follow them. In this case when we issued a delete query from SQL alchemy, SQL alchemy only deleted the rows from the table specified, then the database deleted these entries from the other tables.